# NullPointerException with read properties file in java

Tags: java, swing, properties, nullpointerexception

When load the properties file I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

This is a simple java swing application, try to read the properties file with following code get `java.lang.NullPointerException`:

```
InputStream inputStream;
Properties properties;

inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Config/config.properties");
properties.load(inputStream);
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception? What variable was null then? How could it be that?

Comment: @ Thorbjørn. it is solved. thanks for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing creating a [properties instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
```

Comment: There is some basic understanding missing here which answering the question directly will not help.

Comment: @user7294900 ooooh, really i missed it. thank you :)